# Please suggest me on below description

Tags: php, magento2.4, magento2.3.5-p1

[Site_Link](https://www.rotolam.com/VirtualRooms/Office_2)

I have refer above link,
I want to create this site in Magento 2,

In this site it has main functionality name is **Virtual Room**.
I want to create that kind of functionality.
So is there any extension available in Magento 2?

Please suggest me some advice on this..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think there's no need for an extension about that kind of feature or functionality of a website. you can do it using pure javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

No need for an extension. How to recreate this functionality:

1. Create a configurable product (Virtual Room Product) with color variations (simple products). Color attribute should be set to visual swatch.
2. Add the appropriate image to every variation, so that when the user clicks on a variation, the image will change.
3. Use css and xml layout in order to place the color swatches on top of the image shown and jquery/javascript in order to create the tooltip effect.